# Getting a direct link to a youtube video given a general link

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I'm making an iOS app that needs to load some youtube videos.
I was wondering if there is a simple way to get the direct link to a video so I can play the video directly instead of loading the normal youtube player page.

So if I have a link like:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tQGqlXX7Zs&feature=youtube_gdata

Can I get a direct link from that to the video?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by direct link, but if it helps, the query string variable `v` is the video ID, so on the url you provided the video id is `6tQGqlXX7Zs`. All you'd need to do is remove the other query string variables (in this case `feature`)

Comment: Thats it! Thanks! Would you mind putting a link to that in the documentation + writing the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link below, the `v` parameter is the link id

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36ADLojIQc0&feature=something&otherparameter=othervalue

So you'd have to simply get video id from the query string ignoring all the other parameters, then you'll end up with something similar to this link below (just with a different id)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36ADLojIQc0

I don't know the location of any specific documentation for this

Answer (score 0):

Even better, would be to take the v parameter from the url (everything after v= until &) and pasting it in this url: http://www.youtube.com/v/YOUTUBEID

YOUTUBEID is whatever the v parameter was, this will give you a direct link to the video and won't have any youtube junk included.

---

Some other info that might interest you:

Try this url scheme out, http://www.youtube.com/v/YOUTUBEID?loop=1&autoplay=1

It will autoplay the video and loop it endlessly.

One flaw with that scheme is that it treats those videos as embedded videos and can block you from watching some copyrighted videos.